# Gradle unable to find existing m2 library

Tags: gradle, maven-central, j2v8

Can anyone tell me why gradle fails to load j2v8 dependency with the following script :

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

test {
    useTestNG()
    include '**'
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:18.0"
    compile "com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0"
    compile 'com.eclipsesource.j2v8:j2v8_linux_x86_64:3.1.6'
    testCompile "org.testng:testng:6.9.9"
}
```

using 'com.eclipsesource.j2v8:j2v8_linux_x86_64:3.1.1' works well but with 3.1.6 I get the error Error:(18, 13) Failed to resolve: com.eclipsesource.j2v8:j2v8_linux_x86_64:3.1.6

Answer (score 0):

To use local maven's m2 cache:

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}
```

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. Try `--refresh-dependencies` ?